# To what do the two relative pronouns "which" refer?

Tags: grammar, commas, pronouns, which-that

In the sentence:

> *The sense that life as a whole is absurd arises when we perceive, perhaps dimly, an inflated pretension or aspiration **which** is inseparable from the continuation of human life and **which** makes its absurdity inescapable, short of escape from life itself.*

To what do the two relative pronouns "**which**" refer here? That is, what is inseparable from life and what makes its absurdity inescapable? The "pretension or apiration" or the "perceiving"? How can one tell here? Would one utilize a comma while the other wouldn't? Is there a difference between AmE and BrE?

Thanks

Comment: "Which" refers to "inflated pretension or aspiration". Twice. The word "which" might, in some contexts, refer to the "perceiving" (a gerund) but not to "we perceive". If there were a comma after "aspiration" it would confuse things a little, but wouldn't clearly change the meaning to your alternative. BrE btw, though I don't *think* there's a difference.

Comment: I think the text is basically pretentious waffle anyway, but ***in principle*** the word "which" could refer EITHER to the entire noun phrase "an inflated pretension or aspiration" OR just the word "aspiration" (in which context I'd ***also*** say there's potential ambiguity regarding whether "inflated" modifies just "pretension" or also "aspiration"). But I don't see that any decision about how to parse those two elements makes any difference to what little meaning there is in this "self-referentially absurd" text.

Comment: Yes, the antecent is "inflated pretension or aspiration," and in AE I'd rely on *that-that* to do the job of *which-which* to introduce the restrictives.